# How to calculate the line integral of this intersection

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, parametrization, line-integrals

Given $f(x,y,z) = \sqrt{1+4x^2z^2}$. How do I calculate the line integral along the intersection between $x^2+z^2 = 1$ and $y=x^2$? 
I found this parametrization:

$\vec{r} : t \rightarrow (t, t^2, \sqrt{1-t^2})$, with $a <t <b$, but I don't know how to find $a$ and $b$.

I tried using $\int_a^b f(\vec{r}(t)) \| \frac{dr}{dt} \| dt$, but I couldn't solve it using that formula.

Comment: It should be easy to find the maximum and minimum values of $x$ for the first cylinder. Start from there and see what that gives you on the second cylinder.

Comment: Consider the projection of the curve onto the $xz$-plane. To simplify things, take a parametrization of $x^2 + z^2 = 1$ which doesn't involve square roots. Then the integrand will also simplify to something that doesn't involve square roots.